# Do Racket finalizers run on program exit?

Tags: racket

Consider the following code, which creates a simple table (alist) of age-related capabilities, attaching a finalizer to the data structure:

```
#lang racket
(require ffi/unsafe/alloc)

(define (finalize-capabilities-table ignored)
  (printf "finalizing capabilities table\n"))

(define make-capabilities-table
  ((allocator finalize-capabilities-table)
   (lambda ()
     (printf "creating capabilities table\n")
     '((16 . drive)
       (18 . vote)
       (21 . drink)))))

(make-capabilities-table)
```

I expect this code, when run, to produce

```
creating capabilities table
'((16 . drive) (18 . vote) (21 . drink))
finalizing capabilities table
```

However, I observe that the last message – `finalizing capabilities table` – does not print.  Why not?  Did I fail to attach the finalizer correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the value returned by the function is from a `quote` expression, so the list is allocated once when the function's code is compiled/loaded, and a reference to that constant is held by the function. The following allocates a fresh (outer) list instead:

```
(define make-capabilities-table
  ((allocator finalize-capabilities-table)
   (lambda ()
     (printf "creating capabilities table\n")
     (list '(16 . drive)
           '(18 . vote)
           '(21 . drink)))))
```

Second, the finalizer seems to be run in a thread with the current output and error ports parameterized to suppresses output.  The [docs for `register-finalizer`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/foreign_pointer-funcs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._ffi/unsafe..rkt%29._register-finalizer%29%29) say:

> The given finalizer procedure should generally not rely on the
>   environment of the triggering thread, such as its output ports or
>   custodians, except that relying on a default logger is reasonable.

You can get around that (for the purpose of testing, at least) with the following:

```
(define err (current-error-port))
(define (finalize-capabilities-table ignored)
  (fprintf err "finalizing capabilities table\n"))
```

Finally, finalizers aren't run as soon as a value becomes unreachable; they're only run when the GC notices, and the GC doesn't run after every REPL interaction. You can prompt the GC to run with `(collect-garbage)`.

Comment: Are the GC and associated finalizers guaranteed to run prior to program exit?  Or should I use some other mechanism to ensure cleanup occurs?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You should probably use a custodian instead.